# How to replace if-else "months" code to "months" from enum's?

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to replace my if-else statement with the enum code I just created on other .java file.
However Im not sure how can I replace it with the enum code provided below. Since the if-else code feels repetitive and I thought maybe enum can help shorten the Main.java file.

Main.java

```
if (month.equals("1")) {
            month = "January";
        } else if (month.equals("2")) {
            month = "February";
        } else if (month.equals("3")) {
            month = "March";
        } else if (month.equals("4")) {
            month = "April";
        } else if (month.equals("5")) {
            month = "May";
        } else if (month.equals("6")) {
            month = "June";
        } else if (month.equals("7")) {
            month = "July";
        } else if (month.equals("8")) {
            month = "August";
        } else if (month.equals("9")) {
            month = "September";
        } else if (month.equals("10")) {
            month = "October";
        } else if (month.equals("11")) {
            month = "November";
        } else if (month.equals("12")) {
            month = "December";
        }
```

Months.java (enum)

```
package enums;

public enum Months {
  JANUARY("1", "January"),
  FEBRUARY("2", "February"),
  MARCH("3", "March"),
  APRIL("4", "April"),
  MAY("5", "May"),
  JUNE("6", "June"),
  JULY("7", "July"),
  AUGUST("8", "August"),
  SEPTEMBER("9", "September"),
  OCTOBER("10", "October"),
  NOVEMBER("11", "November"),
  DECEMBER("12", "December");

  Months(String code, String description) {
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
  }

  private String code;

  private String description;

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }

  public static Months convertToEnum(String value) {
    Months m = null;
    for (Months month : Months.values()) {
      if (month.code.contentEquals(value)) {
        m = month;
      }
    }
    return m;
  }

  public static String convertToValue(Months item) {
    String value = "";
    for (Months month : Months.values()) {
      if (month.equals(item)) {
        value = month.getCode();
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you have the code for the replacement but you haven't tried running it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to replace that if-else into the Main.java I was required to do so but im kinda new to this so my apologies

Comment: have you tried to call `convertToEnum` with a value?  Quick style pointer, enums should not be pluralised, i.e MONTH rather than MONTHS.  I dont think you need the method `convertToValue` and what would happen if you made the following call `convertToEnum("hello")`?

Comment: Also consider to use the Month enum from the JDK: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `String` like

```
String month = "3";
```

then you can simply use

```
month = Months.convertToEnum(month).getDescription();
```